How to check Office Proplus product key if I already used unpkey?
I have a laptop that comes with Office Proplus 2019 activated. I used cscript /unpkey to remove it from the system because it interfering with my Office 365 installation (it kept activating as Proplus 2019 instead of Office 365).
I don't have the full product key, but I want to preserve it when in the future I don't use Office 365.
Since I have removed the product key, how to recover the license? Ideally, I would want to note the full product key. I'm not sure if this is OEM since it comes activated.
Note: preferably I don't want to use dodgy tools like in this question, because my antivirus kept blocking them.

You should find this more acceptable but the original purchase source should have the full license key. I am shocked that you were able to successfully use a  product that requires a KMS without a KMS.

@Ramhound since it's on the Microsoft Store I'll try it. Tried on another computer and it doesn't detect the license key thought - is it because it's linked to a microsoft account?

Office Proplus 2019 License key cannot be linked to a Microsoft Account. Office Proplus 2019 Requires a KMS
